# Google Analytics eCommerce tracking all shown as 'direct/none'

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

My eCommerce tracking is working with one exception.  All transactions are being grouped as though they came from the same source/medium **'direct/none'**.

This is my code;

```
<script>

    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-12345678-2', 'auto', 'ecommerceTracker', { 'allowLinker': true });
    ga('ecommerceTracker.require', 'linker');
    ga('ecommerceTracker.linker:autoLink', ['securedomain.com']);
    ga('ecommerceTracker.send', 'pageview');

    ga('ecommerceTracker.require', 'ecommerce');

    ga('ecommerceTracker.ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      id: '123456', // Transaction ID - this is normally generated by your system.
      affiliation: '1', // Affiliation or store name
      revenue: '99.99', // Grand Total
      shipping: '0' , // Shipping cost
      tax: '0' }); // Tax.

    ga('ecommerceTracker.ecommerce:send');

</script>
```

I know that at least one of the transactions should of been listed under 'trivago / cpc', as I created this transaction myself.

The only other point to note, is that this transaction process is being carried out across 2 domains.

This is a sample path a user will take;

1. Visit 3rd party site, in this case Trivago
2. Click on link, redirecting to our domainname.com
3. Navigate through our domainname.com pages
4. Find rooms you want to book
5. Once you have selected the rooms, navigate to the checkout page
6. The checkout page is hosted on the domain securedomain.com
7. From our domainname.com we are redirected to securedomain.com, which contains the same Google Analytics code.
8. The reservation is saved, and transaction recorded in Google Analytics, but is being shown as 'direct/none'.

One other point to add is that the source domain is http and the destination domain is https.  In order to get from the http domain to the https domain, there is a form post.

[image]

Comment: have you setup Google Analytics cross domain tracking between domainname.com and securedomain.com?

Comment: Tell me what I need to set with regards the cross domain tracking ?

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because the _ga identifier isn't carried through the booking process, so that on the point of conversion the dynamic URL identifier is removed and therefore Google Analytics is referencing the conversion as if it came from a direct source.

I have the same problem and found that this was the case.

See here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-analyticsjs/kZ8W4iMxAQQ